# Unreal Engine without Blueprints

Tags: unreal-4, unreal, blueprints

Hello fellow coders I have been using Unity and other game dev libraries fora fun hobby for many years (on-and-off, I am no expert!). But I really am not happy with Unity and their multiplayer network offerings. I've always wanted to master C++ in the end and also Unreal, so now is the time I will delete Unity and only use UE4 for some time.

I jump into UE4 and many tutorials (official UE website and MANY others paid and free). All of them leap straight into Blueprint system. Every time I watch/read these tutorials I think at the end, that surely the Blueprints part is unnecessary, bloated way of achieving something that can easily be achieved purely in c++ code.

I intend to ONLY work on my own. Not part of any team, and my work will never be built upon by anyone but me. 
Personally I dislike visual coding. I hate moving the mouse to small areas and drag-dropping stuff etc.

Will I lose out on any functions etc in the Unreal API if I decide to shun the entire blueprint system?

What reason is there to use Blueprint if you find written code easier?

Not trying to start a flame-war, just want some experienced devs to give me their educated opinion on this matter.

If it was left to me, I would learn to make some basic games in pure code using Unreal API and then I might try to recreate  the same project allowing myself to use blueprints and I will see what takes longer.

But right now I don't even know how to access User Input polling values etc in Unreal, I am about to start learning it all now. Just want to set off on the correct path FOR ME :D

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think I am in the same mindset as you are. 
Yes you can work in 100% C++.

My own project is 95% C++ I only use BPs for instantiating stuff (putting actors to the level) but every single BP of mine is nothing else than just a default values setter.

It is much faster to set default values in BPs as well as performing visual stuff - for example moving some scene-components in BP is much easier than moving them in C++.

Comment: Thank u for the reply. I figure i should try to thoroughly learn and use both with and without blueprint and I will also find good uses for them once I have gotten used to using them. Its good to hear from someone who isn't using the blueprints nodes for every little thing

Comment: @I_Keep_Trying If you want to do C++ then there are some good courses on Udemy